# Is there any pros and cons of calling one constructor from another?

Tags: java, constructor

Consider the following case of calling one constructor from another:

```
public Pet(int x) {
    this.x = x; // “this” means this object
}
public Pet (int x, String y) {
    this(x);    // calls constructor public Pet(int id)
    this.y = y; // ”this” means this object
}
.
.
.
public Pet (params,[...]) { // [...] shows the number of params
    this(params,[...])
    //...
}
```

And separate overloaded constructor body.

```
public Pet(int x, int y, int z, int a, int b, [...]) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    //[...] and so on 
}
```

This is obvious goal can achieve with less lines of code. 
(According above scenario my question)

Is this good/bad practice to call one constructor from another? What will be the pros and cons when we are developing enterprise applications; if we think with respect of performance, memory etc.

Comment: The big pro is that one should **avoid to duplicate code** if the constructor `Foo(x)` is responsible for the "x"-ness of the Foo object, let it initialize the "x"-aspect of the object and the constructor Foo(x,y) initializes the additional "y"-aspect of Foo but leaves the "x"-stuff to the other constructor.

Comment: The main advantage is not having to repeat the initialisation of the same variables in all constructors. One disadvantage is that you can't make the fields you are only setting in some of the constructors final.

Comment: I've removed the `c++` tag, because this doesn't seem to have anything to do with C++, syntax- or semantics-wise. If your question *does* concern C++, please edit it to make that more obvious before adding the tag back.

Comment: @Angew What we see is clearly Java code but C++11 supports the same feature so the semantics is the same.

Comment: Thank you for nice comments. **avoid to duplicate code** is true. There will be stack of constructors when call each other like recursion. Enterprise application doesn't limited to one to two classes. For multiple classes application stack can overflow.

Comment: @Oncaphillis A similar feature. In C++11, a delegating ctor cannot have other mem-initialisers, only code. That's why I consider this a Java question unless the C++ specifics are explicitly called out in the question. In general, two languages are seldom similar enough to be covered by the same question. Better ask two, usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always be following the [Rules of Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization) when thinking about whether or not something is performant and/or optimal to use in certain scenarios.

That aside, there are some clear pros and cons.

The pro to this approach is **less duplicated code**.  With each constructor being added in, the calls to `super` get a bit longer, but there's no repeated operation of `this.x = x` anywhere.

The con to this approach is that you **expose more ways to construct this object**, when you may be looking for a factory or a builder instead which reduces the visibility of the multiple constructor approach.

Comment: Thank you for answer. There will be stack of constructors when call each other like recursion. Enterprise application doesn't limited to one to two classes. For multiple classes application stack can overflow.

Comment: Yes, a stack entry will be created, but unless you have some ungodly number of constructors (on the order of *hundreds*) chained together, you shouldn't run into any stack overflows.

Answer (score 0):

This is much better than duplicating initialization code in multiple constructors. Performance and memory should not be affected. Just more clean code.

Answer (score 0):

it's not about cons and pros, it's about an aim to what you're trying to reach.
generally speaking calling one constructor from another is not a bad practice and if you're lessening the prospective (likely duplicate) code, then you better use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, when you are instantiating your classes, there will be a lot of times when you will not get values for all the properties, or maybe none.

I pretty much always make a full and an empty constructor, because sometimes I need to instantiate the classes without assigning values to the properties until later, so I guess it pretty much depends on what your code does.

Also another important thing is, that it's good to have some flexibility on your code while not making a mess, because when you are working on a project with more people, odds are high that someone will need to use or change your code afterwards, and the more flexible your code is, the other people will have an easier time working with it.